# calling stored procedure which returns multiple rows

Tags: java, stored-procedures

**calling stored procedure from java**

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pw);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    CallableStatement st=con.prepareCall("{call myProcedure(?,?)}");
    st.setString(1,"hibernate");
    st.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(2));

    }
```

i am not able to fetch multiple records from DB.can anyone guide me in this regard.thanks

**here is my procedure**

```
create or replace procedure myProcedure(eskill varchar2,eid out number)
is
cursor c 
is
select empid from emp_skills where skill=eskill;
begin
open c;
loop
fetch c into eid;
exit when c%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line('name of the emp with skill '||eskill|| ' ' ||eid);
end loop;
close c;
end myProcedure;
/
```

Comment: What is your current result and what is your expected result?

Comment: current result is following exception:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

Comment: want to get empIds who has a particular skill.EX :"hibernate" in above code, many employees can have "hibernate" as  skill.i want to get that employees IDs.